# Let's support Dark Mode!

Tags: feature-request, design

> With the introduction of dark mode in macOS, Safari Technology Preview 68 has released a new feature called prefers-color-scheme which lets us detect whether the user has dark mode enabled with a media query.

- https://css-tricks.com/dark-modes-with-css/

As a site based around Apple products, I think it would be pretty cool to support dark mode CSS media queries.  Safari is the first major browser to support this and I think other browsers are likely to follow.

I would also suggest adding a toggle in Settings as many people use Chrome who [doesn't currently support this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme).

Below is the media query:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {

}
```

Comment: The "dark theme" in general has been suggested [since 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111399/241919) though...

Comment: @AndrewT. Oh...

Comment: Sounds like it’s about time!

Comment: I’m reading the site on my iPad in a darkened room and it’s blinding. Yes, please, Dark Mode!